# chromdb query raise "RuntimeError: Cannot open file" error

Tags: chromadb

Please help me to fix the issue, thanks so much!

chromadb == 0.3.26

langchain == 0.0.212

```
    a=self.collection.peek()

    query_results = self.collection.query(
        query_embeddings = [embeddingdata_for_query],
        n_results=5
    )
```

peek() can work,but query() raise runtime error:
RuntimeError: Cannot open file

Great appreciate any suggestion, thanks!